# Reload page after switching toggle switch back on

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc, toggle

I want the page to reload after the toggle is switched back to data-on
JSP:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="expander" id="toggle"
                                data-on="Portfolio" data-off="Topology" checked
                                data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success">
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $('#toggle').change(function() {
        if (this.checked)
            $('#project-list-area').fadeIn('slow'),
            $('#topology').fadeOut('slow');
            count++;
        if (count === 2)
            window.location.reload;
        else
            $('#topology').fadeIn('slow'),
            $('#project-list-area').fadeOut('slow');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use brackets for your `if` and `else if` is more than 1 line.

Also `window.location.reload()` is a method so you need parentheses.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $('#toggle').change(function() {
      if (this.checked){
          $('#project-list-area').fadeIn('slow'),
          $('#topology').fadeOut('slow');
          count++;
      }

      if (count === 2) 
          window.location.reload();

      else{
          $('#topology').fadeIn('slow'),
          $('#project-list-area').fadeOut('slow');
      }

  });
});
```

cleaned up a bit, check out `toggleFade()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;

  $('#toggle').change(function() {
      if (this.checked) count++;
      if (count === 2) window.location.reload();

      $('#topology').fadeToggle('slow'),
      $('#project-list-area').fadeToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

User if ($(this).prop("checked")) instead of if (this.checked) and window.location.reload(); is a method

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 0;
    $('#toggle').change(function () {
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $('#project-list-area').fadeIn('slow'),
            $('#topology').fadeOut('slow');
        }
        count++;
        if (count === 2)
            window.location.reload();
        else {
            $('#topology').fadeIn('slow'),
            $('#project-list-area').fadeOut('slow');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: why ($(this).prop("checked")) instead of if (this.checked) ?